# How to catch FileNameExtensionFilter and make logic for them?

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I have `JFileChooser` and add 2 file extension filter like this:

```
openFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
openFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("D:/"));
openFileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("OUT Files", "out"));
openFileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("PRN Files", "prn"));
```

If i have .out files my logic works but when I choose .prn files the logic for .out files works for the .prn files. My question is how to catch which type is and with if (.out files) --> make something else(.prn files) --> something do?

Comment: If the answer is not along the lines of `if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".out"))` once a file is selected, then .. I don't understand what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your question/problem clearly, so i am going to give you a sample of a file chooser with 2 filters which might help you. The following `JFileChooser` allows user to choose only **Mp3** and **Mp4** files (in your case .out/.prn files?). Read the comments inside the code.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class FileChooserExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File desktop = new File(home, "Desktop");
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(desktop);
        // Add filter for mp3 files.
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Mp3 Files";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                // Show only mp3 Files(which can be selected) and folders (which can be OPENED)
                return isMp3(f) || f.isDirectory();
            }
        });
        // Add filter for mp4 files.
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Mp4 Files";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                // Show only mp4 Files(which can be selected) and folders (which can be OPENED)
                return isMp4(f) || f.isDirectory();
            }
        });
        // Only files allowed. If it is a directory, do not select it but open it to
        // choose files
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        // Remove the "All files" filter. We want only our custom file filters to take
        // action.
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (isMp3(selectedFile)) {
                System.out.println("This is an mp3 file, and i wanna dance.");
            } else if (isMp4(selectedFile)) {
                System.out.println("This is an mp4 file, and i wanna grab pop corn.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isMp4(File f) {
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp4");
    }

    private static boolean isMp3(File f) {
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3");
    }
}
```